# How to make seperated migration work properly with just yii migrate?

Tags: yii2, migrate

I have seperated `migrations` and `module migrations`. Now If I want to migrate, I have to use different commands to migrate each of the module. How can I make that all the modules, all the migrations would work with just `yii migrate`?

Comment: You can't. You have to specify each migration path.

Comment: So what's the point of the whole migration if I have to use 30 commands to create the database? I know somehow it's possible

Comment: You can make it in a way so that inside the regular yii migrations you will call all your modules migrations, one by one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try to read more about that